# xUnit test class internal

Tags: c#, xunit, access-modifiers, base-class

I need xUnit to work with internal test classes.
The problem is that I have used a generic base test fixture UnitTestBase.
So I create my fixture as

```cs
class MyFixture: UnitTestBase<SomeSystemUnderTheTest>
{
...
}
```

In some cases `SomeSystemUnderTheTest` appears to be internal class. Lets call it `SomeSystemUnderTheTestInternal`. As result `UnitTestBase<SomeSystemUnderTheTestInternal>` also appear to be internal even if `UnitTestBase` public. As result of that I can't specify `MyFixture` to be public as compiler says your base class has less accessibility. So MyFixture in my case only can be internal, but then xUnit requires it to be public. Is there a workaround to make xUnit work with internal fixtures?

SomeSystemUnderTheTest is a class which implements some interface. It is not used directly anywhere it is just got injected by DI container. It was marked as internal. I have slightly simplified our situation above, SomeSystemUnderTheTest is in fact derived from a generic class SomeSystemUnderTheTestBase, where SomeInternalClass is an internal class and as result of this the whole tree is internal. I can't change it as it is not something we wanna do.

Comment: What is `SomeSystemUnderTheTest` ? Why is appears to be internal class in some cases? Does it appear a public class in other cases? How?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have updated the question and explained what is the class and why it is internal

Comment: You don't really need that last paragraph explaining why a class may be internal. It's perfectly reasonable for a class to be internal! I'd just say "In some cases `SomeSystemUnderTheTest` will be an internal class" instead of "appears to be".

Answer (score 3):

Add this just above the namespace declaration in your `SomeSystemUnderTestInternal` file:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleToAttribute("TestProject")]
```

Where `TestProject` is the assembly name of the project that contains your test class.

Comment: I have this already it and it doesn't help. It might help if same attribute will be added to xUnit assemblies but I really doubt. xUnit explicitly says the test class should be public.

Comment: This just allows your test project to see your main project's internals. What the OP (and I) need would be an equivalent to put in the test project that allows the test project's internals to be visible to xUnit. You can do something similar for Moq (make main project's internals visible to Moq) - put `<AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
      <_Parameter1>DynamicProxyGenAssembly2</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>` in csproj, but it doesn't appear to be possible for Xunit. Maybe it would be too complicated for test classes, I don't know.